# Socket programming is not working

Tags: java, network-programming

I am using Socket programming in Java. It is Working properly in my computer. But when I run the server in my computer and run the client in another computer it was not working. But When i run the server in another computer and run the client in my computer its working.

Comment: Could be a fire wall issue, could be port forwarding issue...no idea without some idea of the errors/exceptions you are running into.  Also verify that you can ping the server computer from the client

Comment: Seems there is some issue with the your DNS settings .. Are you using a linux machine ??

Comment: @ShuhailKadavath Good point, we need details!

Comment: When you say not working, wht does it mean? do you get any exception?

Comment: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)

Comment: This is the exception message

Comment: This means that the machine cannot find the remote computer .. Please send me the IP address of both the machines and the subnet.

Comment: Instead of just IP address provide socket address(IP + Port). Most likely port issue(maybe due to firewall)

Comment: @AniketThakur.. Yes you are right

Comment: Can you please check the firewall status ? Can you please try with the firewall turned off ?

Comment: Firewall is problem. Now it is working. Thank you so much every body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case stack trace and some code snippet can be very hepful. However I can assume the following reasons:

1. firewall
2. routing

To check routing try to ping server from client. If ping works you probably have a firewall problem. If both computers are in the same network check personal firewall configuration. Probably your server computer does not allow "strangers" to connect to port that you have chosen.

I personally usually try to stop the filrewalls on both machines first. If this helps I start them again and learn how to create firewall rule that allows my application to work.

Comment: Thank you so much. firewall problem. Now it is working

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot ping to your server , maybe your server is behind a router, in this case, your router should be configured to redirect your request from your route to your server.Well ,on the other hand ,you should shut down you firewall.If you server is a linux one, in some cases, even if you can ping to your server, you still have no access to your web service.So ,you should also shut down your selinux.